# Use of "trying to" in place of "wanting to" in the US

Tags: etymology, american-english, slang

Is the use of "trying to" in place of "wanting to" occurring nationwide or regionally?  What is its prevalence and when did it start?

I'm in my late 20s and live in New England.  In the past 2-3 years, I've noticed people starting to use this phrase.  I've heard this in people from New England, Brooklyn, and Pennsylvania for scope.  Here are some examples of how I've heard it, immediately followed with the response it invokes in me.

`You trying to play golf after work?`
^No, at this moment, I am not actively attempting to play golf.

`You trying to grab some lunch?`
^No, I am not actively trying to grab lunch, but I would like to get lunch.

`Hey, I'm not trying to have a hangover tomorrow!`
^Of course nobody would *try* to have a hangover tomorrow.

But in these instances, the speaker is not asking or declaring about an *intentional attempt* to do something; they are indicating a *desire* to do something.

This use just strikes me as odd.

Comment: Try to: want to: the slang dictionary has an entry from 2010. - http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/try-to

Comment: It's no US English per se, but more colloquial, maybe strictly AAVE.

Comment: @DanBron What's "AAVE"?

Comment: @TrevorD African-American Vernacular English

Comment: "Are you *trying* to have a hangover?" would be asked in a situation where the questionee's behavior is such that a hangover would appear likely.  It does not imply conscious intent.  The use of the idiom in this fashion goes back at least 50 years.

Comment: I prefer tryna.

Comment: BET *tryna* = CMT *fixinta*

Comment: @choster nah its just *finna*

Answer (score 1):

I am American, and I experience a lot of diverse usage, American and other  varieties of English. 
Should I be asked one of the stated questions, I would not have a sense of simple want.
Those questions imply *want* and a bit more. To me they would also imply means and capability.
*You trying to play golf after work?* would imply to me: "Do you have things arranged so you can play golf after work?" I think the examples cited are just simple ways of asking a comprehensive question, and probably more urban than not. Rural folks might ask the same with something like   "You lookin' to play golf after work?", or, "Can you see to play golf after work?"
I may be advantaged by having used English, and, having it used on me, for quite a few decades. I just do not see this usage of the verb *to try* as being very odd. I have experienced much odder usage. It is possible the cited examples were queries only as to *desire* or *want* but I think the use of *to try* suggests more. It certainly does to me.
The time, I think, to worry about usage is when no sense can be made of it by the listener.